# Comment « tu es » est devenu « t'es »?

Tags: oral, registre-familier, élision

Je me demande comment et quand  « tu es » a donné « t'es » dans le français parlé relâché et comment s'appelle ce phénomène de la langue orale.

Est-ce un type d'élision ? Dans quels autres cas le rencontre-t-on ? Son emploi est répandu chez toute la francophonie ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oui, il s'agit bien d'un type d'élision. Elle n'est normalement pas marquée à l'écrit mais se rencontre fréquemment à l'oral, en particulier dans la langue non soutenue.

L'élision du *u* de *tu* a certainement une origine très ancienne puisqu'on la retrouve dans un texte du Moyen Âge (Huon de Bordeaux):

> [T’as bon haubert et çaint le branc forbi](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Anonyme_-_Huon_de_Bordeaux,_chanson_de_geste.djvu/161)

dont ma tentative de traduction est:

> Tu as une bonne cotte de maille et le bras qui la ceint est prêt...

L'élision de *tu es* ou *tu as* est courante en région parisienne en plus généralement dans les régions françaises correspondant à la langue d'oil. Cette élision est plus rare dans le sud de la France où, au moins à Marseille, on entend une autre prononciation où le *u* de *tu* se transforme en *i* pour donner "ti as" (parfois écrit *t'y as* ou *t'ias*).

D'autres pronoms peuvent être aussi sujets à des évolutions de prononciation :

> je viens → j'viens
>
> je ne sais pas → je sais pas → j'sais pas → chais pas
>
> il vient → y vient
>
> il est pas bien malin → l'est pas bien malin
>
> elle n'est pas bien [mali(g)ne](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/laurence-p-lamotte-beuvron) → l'est pas bien maline
>
> elle vient → è vient
>
> vous avez raison → z'avez raison
>
> ils ont gagné  → z'ont gagné

Comment: +1 jlliagre. Juste pour ajouter à ta compile des évolutions de pronoms : *il ou elle -> L'* dans par ex : *L'est pas bien malin* - *L'a pas d'chance*...

Comment: Pour arriver à "chais pas" je partirais même de "je *ne* sais pas"...

Comment: *Maligne* sérieusement? Avec ce sens on dit *maline* de nos jours…

Comment: Probablement seulement à Marseille ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez J'ai toujours prononcé *mali**ne*** mais m'efforce d'écrire *mali**gne*** depuis que mon instituteur m'a fait remarquer que c'était l'orthographe correcte... L'erreur est de toute façon ***bénine*** ;-)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Probablement plus qu'à Marseille, peut-être toute la Provence. Il faut aussi ajouter l'accent pied-noir qui dit aussi *t'y as*.

Answer (score 3):

Oui, c'est un type d'élision.

On emploie diverses stratégies pour résoudre le hiatus, c'est-à-dire une séquence de deux voyelles ou plus à la suite.

La stratégie qu'on voit ici est de supprimer tout simplement l'une des voyelles, normalement la première. Lorsque cette voyelle est /ə/ (voyelle réduite du point de vue de la phonologie) cette résolution est répandue dans tous les registres, comme tu le sais :

> Le gros âne
>
> L'âne

Mais la voyelle /y/ que comporte « tu » /ty/ n'y succombe qu'au niveau populaire, et oui, cela se passe également dans bien d'autres cas :

> T'as vu ça ?
>
> T'aurais pas voulu ...
>
> T'étais en train de dire quelque chose ?

C'est qu'à l'oral et dans la langue non « soignée » on met l'accent sur l'énonciation fluide, rapide, facile. Une séquence de voyelles n'est qu'une séquence de mouvements de la langue et des lèvres sans intérruption. Cela tend à produire des semi-voyelles (e.g. « tu es » /tɥe/) dont l'élision s'ensuit assez souvent.

On notera que seulement « tu » se comporte *exactement* ainsi parmi les pronoms sujets, en ce que concerne le hiatus. C'est que « je » termine déjà par /ə/ déjà et donc l'élision est la stratégie préférée dans tous les registres, tandis que tous les autres pronoms sujets terminent par une consonne, donc il n'y a pas de hiatus.

---

Une autre stratégie pour résoudre le hiatus est d'insérer une consonne, p.ex. /t/ :

> Il a chanté.
>
> A-**t**-il chanté ?

Ceci se produit dans certains registres là où c'est interdit à l'écrit, p.ex. /z/ :

> Donne-moi-en.
>
> Donne-moi-**z**-en !

Cette consonne est parfois le vestige d'une ancienne forme, p.ex. /l/ :

> Un beau cheval
>
> Un bel âne

---

Et il y a des mots dont le hiatus fait partie, tels que « Hawaï », indiqué en français par le tréma.