# Élision: pourquoi dans « j’espère » et pas dans « tu espères » ?

Tags: élision

Pourquoi le phénomène d'élision se rencontre, p. ex., dans « *j'espère* » et pas dans « *tu espères* » ? Quelle est la différence ?

Quand l'élision est-elle nécessaire ?

---

Why is the phenomenon of elision encountered for instance in "*j'espère*" and not in "*tu espères*"? What is the difference ?

When is elision necessary?

Comment: I edited your question. I think it reflects better your queries now.

Comment: See also https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31166/comment-tu-es-est-devenu-tes/31168#31168

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elision is not used formally for "tu"; it's simply a matter of usage; in the spoken language it is acceptable and rendered by "t'espères" in print; however it can be considered as quite lax by many.

Elision is necessary for "je" when the verb that follows starts by a vowel; when the verb starts with "h", usage varies.

> Je happe, j'honore, je hasarde, [(très rare)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=j%27hasarde%2Cje+hasarde&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cj%27hasarde%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cje%20hasarde%3B%2Cc0) j'hasarde

In fact, the difference is a matter of whether "h" is  one or the other of the so-called "*h-muet*" and "*h-aspiré*". See for instance the link below;

https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-61194.php